# Accessing columns with MultiIndex after using pandas groupby and aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, multi-index

I am using the `df.groupby()` method:

```
g1 = df[['md', 'agd', 'hgd']].groupby(['md']).agg(['mean', 'count', 'std'])
```

It produces exactly what I want!

```
         agd                       hgd                
        mean count       std      mean count       std
md                                                    
-4  1.398350     2  0.456494 -0.418442     2  0.774611
-3 -0.281814    10  1.314223 -0.317675    10  1.161368
-2 -0.341940    38  0.882749  0.136395    38  1.240308
-1 -0.137268   125  1.162081 -0.103710   125  1.208362
 0 -0.018731   603  1.108109 -0.059108   603  1.252989
 1 -0.034113   178  1.128363 -0.042781   178  1.197477
 2  0.118068    43  1.107974  0.383795    43  1.225388
 3  0.452802    18  0.805491 -0.335087    18  1.120520
 4  0.304824     1       NaN -1.052011     1       NaN
```

However, I now want to access the groupby object columns like a "normal" dataframe.

I will then be able to:
  1) calculate the errors on the `agd` and `hgd` means
  2) make scatter plots on `md` (x axis) vs `agd mean` (`hgd mean`) with appropriate error bars added.

Is this possible? Perhaps by playing with the indexing?

Comment: Related: [Select rows in a pandas DataFrame which has a MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-which-has-a-multiindex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can rename the columns and proceed as normal (will get rid of the multi-indexing)

```
g1.columns = ['agd_mean', 'agd_std','hgd_mean','hgd_std']
```

2) You can keep multi-indexing and use both levels in turn ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#basic-indexing-on-axis-with-multiindex))

```
g1['agd']['mean count']
```

Comment: That helped! Thanks! But how can I plot md on the x axis? It won't let me rename the -4 - +4 md values :/ ....

Comment: If you rename the columns, md is your index and you can access its values by `g1.index.values`. Better still, you can use `g1.plot(...)` and it will use the index as your x values by default (depending on the kind of plot you're making).

Comment: You can change the index values by g1.index = (list or array or whatever).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: Hmmm... g1.plot(x=g1.index.values, y=g1.hgd_mean, kind = "scatter")

doesn't work after the renaming...thoughts?

Comment: Try this instead: `plt.scatter(g1.index,g1.agd_mean)`

Comment: That got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do what you are searching for and it is called `transform`. You will find an example that does exactly what you are searching for in the pandas documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation).