# Select rows in pandas MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, multi-index

**What are the most common pandas ways to select/filter rows of a [dataframe whose index is a MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#)?**

- Slicing based on a single value/label
- Slicing based on multiple labels from one or more levels
- Filtering on boolean conditions and expressions
- Which methods are applicable in what circumstances

Assumptions for simplicity:

1. input dataframe does not have duplicate index keys
2. input dataframe below only has two levels. (Most solutions shown here generalize to N levels)

---

#### Example input:

> ```
> mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
>     list('aaaabbbbbccddddd'),
>     list('tuvwtuvwtuvwtuvw')
> ], names=['one', 'two'])
>
> df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.arange(len(mux))}, mux)
>
>          col
> one two     
> a   t      0
>     u      1
>     v      2
>     w      3
> b   t      4
>     u      5
>     v      6
>     w      7
>     t      8
> c   u      9
>     v     10
> d   w     11
>     t     12
>     u     13
>     v     14
>     w     15
> ```

### Question 1: Selecting a Single Item

How do I select rows having "a" in level "one"?

```
         col
one two     
a   t      0
    u      1
    v      2
    w      3
```

Additionally, how would I be able to drop level "one" in the output?

```
     col
two     
t      0
u      1
v      2
w      3
```

**Question 1b**
How do I slice all rows with value "t" on level "two"?

```
         col
one two     
a   t      0
b   t      4
    t      8
d   t     12
```

### Question 2: Selecting Multiple Values in a Level

How can I select rows corresponding to items "b" and "d" in level "one"?

```
         col
one two     
b   t      4
    u      5
    v      6
    w      7
    t      8
d   w     11
    t     12
    u     13
    v     14
    w     15
```

**Question 2b**
How would I get all values corresponding to "t" and "w" in level "two"?

```
         col
one two     
a   t      0
    w      3
b   t      4
    w      7
    t      8
d   w     11
    t     12
    w     15
```

### Question 3: Slicing a Single Cross Section `(x, y)`

How do I retrieve a cross section, i.e., a single row having a specific values for the index from `df`? Specifically, how do I retrieve the cross section of `('c', 'u')`, given by

```
         col
one two     
c   u      9
```

### Question 4: Slicing Multiple Cross Sections `[(a, b), (c, d), ...]`

How do I select the two rows corresponding to `('c', 'u')`, and `('a', 'w')`?

```
         col
one two     
c   u      9
a   w      3
```

### Question 5: One Item Sliced per Level

How can I retrieve all rows corresponding to "a" in level "one" or "t" in level "two"?

```
         col
one two     
a   t      0
    u      1
    v      2
    w      3
b   t      4
    t      8
d   t     12
```

### Question 6: Arbitrary Slicing

How can I slice specific cross sections? For "a" and "b", I would like to select all rows with sub-levels "u" and "v", and for "d", I would like to select rows with sub-level "w".

```
         col
one two     
a   u      1
    v      2
b   u      5
    v      6
d   w     11
    w     15
```

> Question 7 will use a unique setup consisting of a numeric level:
>
> ```
> np.random.seed(0)
> mux2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
>     list('aaaabbbbbccddddd'),
>     np.random.choice(10, size=16)
> ], names=['one', 'two'])
>
> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.arange(len(mux2))}, mux2)
>
>          col
> one two     
> a   5      0
>     0      1
>     3      2
>     3      3
> b   7      4
>     9      5
>     3      6
>     5      7
>     2      8
> c   4      9
>     7     10
> d   6     11
>     8     12
>     8     13
>     1     14
>     6     15
> ```

### Question 7: Filtering by numeric inequality on individual levels of the multiindex

How do I get all rows where values in level "two" are greater than 5?

```
         col
one two     
b   7      4
    9      5
c   7     10
d   6     11
    8     12
    8     13
    6     15
```

---

Note: This post will *not* go through how to create MultiIndexes, how to perform assignment operations on them, or any performance related discussions (these are separate topics for another time).

Comment: This looks like a great case for dfsql

 df.sql(<SQL select statement>)

https://github.com/mindsdb/dfsql

https://medium.com/riselab/why-every-data-scientist-using-pandas-needs-modin-bringing-sql-to-dataframes-3b216b29a7c0

Comment: I wonder why this question has never been closed. it asks 7 questions

Answer (score 376, accepted):

#### [MultiIndex / Advanced Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#multiindex-advanced-indexing)

> **Note**
> This post will be structured in the following manner:
>
> 1. The questions put forth in the OP will be addressed, one by one
> 2. For each question, one or more methods applicable to solving this problem and getting the expected result will be demonstrated.
>
> **Note**s (much like this one) will be included for readers interested in learning about additional functionality, implementation details,
> and other info cursory to the topic at hand. These notes have been
> compiled through scouring the docs and uncovering various obscure
> features, and from my own (admittedly limited) experience.
>
> All code samples have created and tested on **pandas v0.23.4, python3.7**. If something is not clear, or factually incorrect, or if you did not
> find a solution applicable to your use case, please feel free to
> suggest an edit, request clarification in the comments, or open a new
> question, ....as applicable.

Here is an introduction to some common idioms (henceforth referred to as the Four Idioms) we will be frequently re-visiting

1. *[`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)* - A general solution for selection by label (+ *[`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.IndexSlice.html)* for more complex applications involving slices)
2. *[`DataFrame.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)* - Extract a particular cross section from a Series/DataFrame.
3. *[`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)* - Specify slicing and/or filtering operations dynamically (i.e., as an expression that is evaluated dynamically. Is more applicable to some scenarios than others. Also see [this section of the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#multiindex-query-syntax) for querying on MultiIndexes.
4. Boolean indexing with a mask generated using *[`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html)* (often in conjunction with *[`Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html)*, especially when filtering with multiple values). This is also quite useful in some circumstances.

It will be beneficial to look at the various slicing and filtering problems in terms of the Four Idioms to gain a better understanding what can be applied to a given situation. It is very important to understand that not all of the idioms will work equally well (if at all) in every circumstance. If an idiom has not been listed as a potential solution to a problem below, that means that idiom cannot be applied to that problem effectively.

---

> #### Question 1
>
> How do I select rows having "a" in level "one"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   t      0
>     u      1
>     v      2
>     w      3
> ```

You can use `loc`, as a general purpose solution applicable to most situations:

```
df.loc[['a']]
```

At this point, if you get

```
TypeError: Expected tuple, got str
```

That means you're using an older version of pandas. Consider upgrading! Otherwise, use `df.loc[('a', slice(None)), :]`.

Alternatively, you can use `xs` here, since we are extracting a single cross section. Note the `levels` and `axis` arguments (reasonable defaults can be assumed here).

```
df.xs('a', level=0, axis=0, drop_level=False)
# df.xs('a', drop_level=False)
```

Here, the `drop_level=False` argument is needed to prevent `xs` from dropping level "one" in the result (the level we sliced on).

Yet another option here is using `query`:

```
df.query("one == 'a'")
```

If the index did not have a name, you would need to change your query string to be `"ilevel_0 == 'a'"`.

Finally, using `get_level_values`:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values('one') == 'a']
# If your levels are unnamed, or if you need to select by position (not label),
# df[df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'a']
```

> Additionally, how would I be able to drop level "one" in the output?
>
> ```
>      col
> two     
> t      0
> u      1
> v      2
> w      3
> ```

This can be *easily* done using either

```
df.loc['a'] # Notice the single string argument instead the list.
```

Or,

```
df.xs('a', level=0, axis=0, drop_level=True)
# df.xs('a')
```

Notice that we can omit the `drop_level` argument (it is assumed to be `True` by default).

> **Note**
> You may notice that a filtered DataFrame may still have all the levels, even if they do not show when printing the DataFrame out. For example,
>
> ```
> v = df.loc[['a']]
> print(v)
>          col
> one two     
> a   t      0
>     u      1
>     v      2
>     w      3
>
> print(v.index)
> MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['t', 'u', 'v', 'w']],
>            labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3]],
>            names=['one', 'two'])
> ```
>
> You can get rid of these levels using [*`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html):
>
> ```
> v.index = v.index.remove_unused_levels()
> ```

> ```
> print(v.index)
> MultiIndex(levels=[['a'], ['t', 'u', 'v', 'w']],
>            labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3]],
>            names=['one', 'two'])
> ```

---

> #### Question 1b
>
> How do I slice all rows with value "t" on level "two"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   t      0
> b   t      4
>     t      8
> d   t     12
> ```

Intuitively, you would want something involving [*`slice()`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice):

```
df.loc[(slice(None), 't'), :]
```

It Just Works!™ But it is clunky. We can facilitate a more natural slicing syntax using the `pd.IndexSlice` API here.

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:, 't'], :]
```

This is much, much cleaner.

> **Note**
> Why is the trailing slice `:` across the columns required? This is because, `loc` can be used to select and slice along both axes (`axis=0` or
> `axis=1`). Without explicitly making it clear which axis the slicing
> is to be done on, the operation becomes ambiguous. See the big red box in the [documentation on slicing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers).
>
> If you want to remove any shade of ambiguity, `loc` accepts an `axis`
> parameter:
>
> ```
> df.loc(axis=0)[pd.IndexSlice[:, 't']]
> ```
>
> Without the `axis` parameter (i.e., just by doing `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 't']]`), slicing is assumed to be on the columns,
> and a `KeyError` will be raised in this circumstance.
>
> This is documented in [slicers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers). For the purpose of this post, however, we will explicitly specify all axes.

With `xs`, it is

```
df.xs('t', axis=0, level=1, drop_level=False)
```

With `query`, it is

```
df.query("two == 't'")
# Or, if the first level has no name, 
# df.query("ilevel_1 == 't'")
```

And finally, with `get_level_values`, you may do

```
df[df.index.get_level_values('two') == 't']
# Or, to perform selection by position/integer,
# df[df.index.get_level_values(1) == 't']
```

All to the same effect.

---

> #### Question 2
>
> How can I select rows corresponding to items "b" and "d" in level "one"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> b   t      4
>     u      5
>     v      6
>     w      7
>     t      8
> d   w     11
>     t     12
>     u     13
>     v     14
>     w     15
> ```

Using loc, this is done in a similar fashion by specifying a list.

```
df.loc[['b', 'd']]
```

To solve the above problem of selecting "b" and "d", you can also use `query`:

```
items = ['b', 'd']
df.query("one in @items")
# df.query("one == @items", parser='pandas')
# df.query("one in ['b', 'd']")
# df.query("one == ['b', 'd']", parser='pandas')
```

> **Note**
> Yes, the default parser is `'pandas'`, but it is important to highlight this syntax isn't conventionally python. The
> Pandas parser generates a slightly different parse tree from the
> expression. This is done to make some operations more intuitive to
> specify. For more information, please read my post on
> [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

And, with `get_level_values` + `Index.isin`:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values("one").isin(['b', 'd'])]
```

---

> #### Question 2b
>
> How would I get all values corresponding to "t" and "w" in level "two"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   t      0
>     w      3
> b   t      4
>     w      7
>     t      8
> d   w     11
>     t     12
>     w     15
> ```

With `loc`, this is possible *only* in conjuction with `pd.IndexSlice`.

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, ['t', 'w']], :]
```

The first colon `:` in `pd.IndexSlice[:, ['t', 'w']]` means to slice across the first level. As the depth of the level being queried increases, you will need to specify more slices, one per level being sliced across. You will not need to specify more levels *beyond* the one being sliced, however.

With `query`, this is

```
items = ['t', 'w']
df.query("two in @items")
# df.query("two == @items", parser='pandas') 
# df.query("two in ['t', 'w']")
# df.query("two == ['t', 'w']", parser='pandas')
```

With `get_level_values` and `Index.isin` (similar to above):

```
df[df.index.get_level_values('two').isin(['t', 'w'])]
```

---

> #### Question 3
>
> How do I retrieve a cross section, i.e., a single row having a specific values
> for the index from `df`? Specifically, how do I retrieve the cross
> section of `('c', 'u')`, given by
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> c   u      9
> ```

Use `loc` by specifying a tuple of keys:

```
df.loc[('c', 'u'), :]
```

Or,

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[('c', 'u')]]
```

> **Note**
> At this point, you may run into a [*`PerformanceWarning`*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.errors.PerformanceWarning.html#pandas-errors-performancewarning) that looks like this:
>
> ```
> PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance.
> ```
>
> This just means that your index is not sorted. pandas depends on the index being sorted (in this case, lexicographically, since we are dealing with string values) for optimal search and retrieval. A quick fix would be to sort your
> DataFrame in advance using [*`DataFrame.sort_index`*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-index). This is especially desirable from a performance standpoint if you plan on doing
> multiple such queries in tandem:
>
> ```
> df_sort = df.sort_index()
> df_sort.loc[('c', 'u')]
> ```
>
> You can also use [*`MultiIndex.is_lexsorted()`*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.is_lexsorted.html) to check whether the index
> is sorted or not. This function returns `True` or `False` accordingly.
> You can call this function to determine whether an additional sorting
> step is required or not.

With `xs`, this is again simply passing a single tuple as the first argument, with all other arguments set to their appropriate defaults:

```
df.xs(('c', 'u'))
```

With `query`, things become a bit clunky:

```
df.query("one == 'c' and two == 'u'")
```

You can see now that this is going to be relatively difficult to generalize. But is still OK for this particular problem.

With accesses spanning multiple levels, `get_level_values` can still be used, but is not recommended:

```
m1 = (df.index.get_level_values('one') == 'c')
m2 = (df.index.get_level_values('two') == 'u')
df[m1 & m2]
```

---

> #### Question 4
>
> How do I select the two rows corresponding to `('c', 'u')`, and `('a', 'w')`?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> c   u      9
> a   w      3
> ```

With `loc`, this is still as simple as:

```
df.loc[[('c', 'u'), ('a', 'w')]]
# df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[[('c', 'u'), ('a', 'w')]]]
```

With `query`, you will need to dynamically generate a query string by iterating over your cross sections and levels:

```
cses = [('c', 'u'), ('a', 'w')]
levels = ['one', 'two']
# This is a useful check to make in advance.
assert all(len(levels) == len(cs) for cs in cses) 

query = '(' + ') or ('.join([
    ' and '.join([f"({l} == {repr(c)})" for l, c in zip(levels, cs)]) 
    for cs in cses
]) + ')'

print(query)
# ((one == 'c') and (two == 'u')) or ((one == 'a') and (two == 'w'))

df.query(query)
```

100% DO NOT RECOMMEND! But it is possible.

**What if I have multiple levels?**
One option in this scenario would be to use [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) to drop the levels you're not checking, then use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) to test membership, and then boolean index on the final result.

```
df[df.index.droplevel(unused_level).isin([('c', 'u'), ('a', 'w')])]
```

---

> #### Question 5
>
> How can I retrieve all rows corresponding to "a" in level "one" or
> "t" in level "two"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   t      0
>     u      1
>     v      2
>     w      3
> b   t      4
>     t      8
> d   t     12
> ```

This is actually very difficult to do with `loc` while ensuring correctness *and* still maintaining code clarity. `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['a', 't']]` is incorrect, it is interpreted as `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[('a', 't')]]` (i.e., selecting a cross section). You may think of a solution with `pd.concat` to handle each label separately:

```
pd.concat([
    df.loc[['a'],:], df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 't'],:]
])

         col
one two     
a   t      0
    u      1
    v      2
    w      3
    t      0   # Does this look right to you? No, it isn't!
b   t      4
    t      8
d   t     12
```

But you'll notice one of the rows is duplicated. This is because that row satisfied both slicing conditions, and so appeared twice. You will instead need to do

```
v = pd.concat([
        df.loc[['a'],:], df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 't'],:]
])
v[~v.index.duplicated()]
```

But if your DataFrame inherently contains duplicate indices (that you want), then this will not retain them.  **Use with extreme caution**.

With `query`, this is stupidly simple:

```
df.query("one == 'a' or two == 't'")
```

With `get_level_values`, this is still simple, but not as elegant:

```
m1 = (df.index.get_level_values('one') == 'a')
m2 = (df.index.get_level_values('two') == 't')
df[m1 | m2]
```

---

> #### Question 6
>
> How can I slice specific cross sections? For "a" and "b", I would like to select all rows with sub-levels "u" and "v", and
> for "d", I would like to select rows with sub-level "w".
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   u      1
>     v      2
> b   u      5
>     v      6
> d   w     11
>     w     15
> ```

This is a special case that I've added to help understand the applicability of the Four Idioms—this is one case where none of them will work effectively, since the slicing is *very* specific, and does not follow any real pattern.

Usually, slicing problems like this will require explicitly passing a list of keys to `loc`. One way of doing this is with:

```
keys = [('a', 'u'), ('a', 'v'), ('b', 'u'), ('b', 'v'), ('d', 'w')]
df.loc[keys, :]
```

If you want to save some typing, you will recognise that there is a pattern to slicing "a", "b" and its sublevels, so we can separate the slicing task into two portions and `concat` the result:

```
pd.concat([
     df.loc[(('a', 'b'), ('u', 'v')), :], 
     df.loc[('d', 'w'), :]
   ], axis=0)
```

Slicing specification for "a" and "b" is slightly cleaner `(('a', 'b'), ('u', 'v'))` because the same sub-levels being indexed are the same for each level.

---

> #### Question 7
>
> How do I get all rows where values in level "two" are greater than 5?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> b   7      4
>     9      5
> c   7     10
> d   6     11
>     8     12
>     8     13
>     6     15
> ```

This can be done using `query`,

```
df2.query("two > 5")
```

And `get_level_values`.

```
df2[df2.index.get_level_values('two') > 5]
```

> **Note**
> Similar to this example, we can filter based on any arbitrary condition using these constructs. In general, it is useful to remember that `loc` and `xs` are specifically for label-based indexing, while `query` and
> `get_level_values` are helpful for building general conditional masks
> for filtering.

---

> #### Bonus Question
>
> What if I need to slice a `MultiIndex` *column*?

Actually, most solutions here are applicable to columns as well, with minor changes. Consider:

```
np.random.seed(0)
mux3 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
        list('ABCD'), list('efgh')
], names=['one','two'])

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(10, (3, len(mux))), columns=mux3)
print(df3)

one  A           B           C           D         
two  e  f  g  h  e  f  g  h  e  f  g  h  e  f  g  h
0    5  0  3  3  7  9  3  5  2  4  7  6  8  8  1  6
1    7  7  8  1  5  9  8  9  4  3  0  3  5  0  2  3
2    8  1  3  3  3  7  0  1  9  9  0  4  7  3  2  7
```

These are the following changes you will need to make to the Four Idioms to have them working with columns.

1. To slice with `loc`, use

   ```
    df3.loc[:, ....] # Notice how we slice across the index with `:`.
   ```

   or,

   ```
    df3.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[...]]
   ```
2. To use `xs` as appropriate, just pass an argument `axis=1`.
3. You can access the column level values directly using `df.columns.get_level_values`. You will then need to do something like

   ```
    df.loc[:, {condition}]
   ```

   Where `{condition}` represents some condition built using `columns.get_level_values`.
4. To use `query`, your only option is to transpose, query on the index, and transpose again:

   ```
    df3.T.query(...).T
   ```

   Not recommended, use one of the other 3 options.

Answer (score 19):

Recently I came across a use case where I had a 3+ level multi-index dataframe in which I couldn't make any of the solutions above produce the results I was looking for. It's quite possible that the above solutions do of course work for my use case, and I tried several, however I was unable to get them to work with the time I had available.

I am far from expert, but I stumbled across a solution that was not listed in the comprehensive answers above. I offer no guarantee that the solutions are in any way optimal.

This is a different way to get a slightly different result to Question #6 above. (and likely other questions as well)

Specifically I was looking for:

1. A way to choose two+ values from one level of the index and a single value from another level of the index, and
2. A way to leave the index values from the previous operation in the dataframe output.

As a monkey wrench in the gears (however totally fixable):

3. The indexes were unnamed.

On the toy dataframe below:

```
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a','b'],
                               ['stock1','stock2','stock3'],
                               ['price','volume','velocity']])

    df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
                      10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18], 
                       index)

                        0
    a stock1 price      1
             volume     2
             velocity   3
      stock2 price      4
             volume     5
             velocity   6
      stock3 price      7
             volume     8
             velocity   9
    b stock1 price     10
             volume    11
             velocity  12
      stock2 price     13
             volume    14
             velocity  15
      stock3 price     16
             volume    17
             velocity  18
```

Using the below works, of course:

```
    df.xs(('stock1', 'velocity'), level=(1,2))

        0
    a   3
    b  12
```

But I wanted a different result, so my method to get that result was:

```
   df.iloc[df.index.isin(['stock1'], level=1) & 
           df.index.isin(['velocity'], level=2)] 

                        0
    a stock1 velocity   3
    b stock1 velocity  12
```

And if I wanted two+ values from one level and a single (or 2+) value from another level:

```
    df.iloc[df.index.isin(['stock1','stock3'], level=1) & 
            df.index.isin(['velocity'], level=2)] 

                        0
    a stock1 velocity   3
      stock3 velocity   9
    b stock1 velocity  12
      stock3 velocity  18
```

The above method is probably a bit clunky, however I found it filled my needs and as a bonus was easier for me to understand and read.

Comment: Using an IndexSlice instead will avoid parsing the index repeatedly. You can achieve the same non-destructive results with `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'stock1', 'velocity'], :]` and `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, ['stock1', 'stock3'], 'velocity'], :]` as cs95 demonstrated already.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a great case for **dfsql**

```
df.sql(<SQL select statement>)
```

https://github.com/mindsdb/dfsql

A complete article about it here:

https://medium.com/riselab/why-every-data-scientist-using-pandas-needs-modin-bringing-sql-to-dataframes-3b216b29a7c0

Comment: Do not provide links only. Please add some examples. Add solutions to the corresponding sub-questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have long used and appreciate this question, and [@cs95](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/cs95)'s response, which is very thorough and handles all instances. Similar to [@r-a](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5489642/r-a)'s answer, I too wanted to find a way to work with multiple indices that contained multiple levels.

I finally found a way to obtain an arbitrary number of slices given a level or a named index, which is able to handle several of the questions proposed above. The major improvement here is not having to parse out `slice(None)` or the `:` with `pd.IndexSlice` for multiple indexes, or slices.

```
import pandas as pd

def slice_df_by(df_, slice_by=["Oman", "Nairobi",], slice_idx='country'):
    idxn = df_.index.names.index(slice_idx)
    return df_.loc[tuple([slice(None)]*idxn +[slice_by] ), :]

gender = tuple(["male", "female"]*6)
thrown = tuple(["rock", "scissors", "paper"]*4) 
country = tuple(["Nairobi", "Oman", "Djibouti", "Belize"]*3) 
names = tuple(["Chris", "Pat", "Michele", "Thomy", "Musa", "Casey"]*2)

tuples = list(zip(gender, thrown, country, names))

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, 
                                names=["gender", "thrown", "country", "name"])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Count A': [12., 70., 30., 20.]*3, 
                   'Count B': [12., 70., 30., 20.]*3}, index=idx)
```

The benefit here is that you can add any combination of these calls to the function `slice_df_by` to get more complicated slices while only using the index name and a list of values.

```
print(slice_df_by(df))

                                 Count A  Count B
gender thrown   country name                     
female scissors Oman    Pat         70.0     70.0
       paper    Oman    Casey       70.0     70.0
       rock     Oman    Thomy       70.0     70.0
male   rock     Nairobi Chris       12.0     12.0
       scissors Nairobi Musa        12.0     12.0
       paper    Nairobi Michele     12.0     12.0
```

The catch, as [@r-a](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5489642/r-a) pointed out is not having named indices. There are plenty of ways to satisfy this using the approach here, such as `df.index.names = ["names", "for", "the", "indices"]` or some such method:

```
idxz = lambda ixln=4: [chr(i) for i in np.arange(ixln)+65]
df.index.names = idxz(len(df.index.names))
print(idxz())
Out[132]: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is excellent, but `.loc(axis=0)` provides a more concise solution when slicing only on the 2nd level, such as questions 1b and 2b. It removes the necessity for `get_level_values` and `pd.IndexSlice`.

---

> #### Question 1b
>
> How do I slice all rows with value "t" on level "two"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   t      0
> b   t      4
>     t      8
> d   t     12
> ```

`df.loc(axis=0)[:,'t']` is all you need.

> #### Question 2b
>
> How would I get all values corresponding to "t" and "w" in level "two"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   t      0
>     w      3
> b   t      4
>     w      7
>     t      8
> d   w     11
>     t     12
>     w     15
> ```

`df.loc(axis=0)[:,['t', 'w']]` is once again all you need.

`axis=0` is equivalent to `axis='rows'`.

Similarly, to slice MultiIndex columns, use `.loc(axis=1)` or `.loc(axis='columns')`

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [select_rows](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select_rows) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
```

> #### Question 1
>
> How do I select rows having "a" in level "one"?

```py
df.select_rows('a') 
         col
one two     
a   t      0
    u      1
    v      2
    w      3
```

> Additionally, how would I be able to drop level "one" in the output?

```py
df.select_rows('a').droplevel('one') 
     col
two     
t      0
u      1
v      2
w      3
```

> #### Question 1b
>
> How do I slice all rows with value "t" on level "two"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   t      0
> b   t      4
>     t      8
> d   t     12
> ```

Use a dictionary here, specify the level as a key, and pass the labels to select:

```py
df.select_rows({'two':'t'})
         col
one two     
a   t      0
b   t      4
    t      8
d   t     12
```

> #### Question 2
>
> How can I select rows corresponding to items "b" and "d" in level "one"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> b   t      4
>     u      5
>     v      6
>     w      7
>     t      8
> d   w     11
>     t     12
>     u     13
>     v     14
>     w     15
> ```

Since selection is on a single level, pass a list of the labels:

```py
df.select_rows(['b','d'])
         col
one two     
b   t      4
    u      5
    v      6
    w      7
    t      8
d   w     11
    t     12
    u     13
    v     14
    w     15
```

> #### Question 2b
>
> How would I get all values corresponding to "t" and "w" in level "two"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   t      0
>     w      3
> b   t      4
>     w      7
>     t      8
> d   w     11
>     t     12
>     w     15
> ```

Use a dictionary:

```py
df.select_rows({'two':['t','w']})
         col
one two     
a   t      0
b   t      4
    t      8
d   t     12
a   w      3
b   w      7
d   w     11
    w     15
```

> #### Question 3
>
> How do I retrieve a cross section, i.e., a single row having a specific values
> for the index from `df`? Specifically, how do I retrieve the cross
> section of `('c', 'u')`, given by
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> c   u      9
> ```

We are going across levels (horizontally, not vertically), a tuple is required:

```py
# sort required to avoid lexsort performance warning
df.sort_index().select_rows(('c','u'))
         col
one two     
c   u      9
```

> #### Question 4
>
> How do I select the two rows corresponding to `('c', 'u')`, and `('a', 'w')`?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> c   u      9
> a   w      3
> ```

`select_rows` accepts multiple variable arguments:

```py
df.sort_index().select_rows(('c','u'), ('a','w'))
         col
one two     
c   u      9
a   w      3
```

> #### Question 5
>
> How can I retrieve all rows corresponding to "a" in level "one" or
> "t" in level "two"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   t      0
>     u      1
>     v      2
>     w      3
> b   t      4
>     t      8
> d   t     12
> ```

```py
df.select_rows('a', {'two':'t'})
         col
one two     
a   t      0
    u      1
    v      2
    w      3
    t      0
b   t      4
    t      8
d   t     12
```

> #### Question 6
>
> How can I slice specific cross sections? For "a" and "b", I would like to select all rows with sub-levels "u" and "v", and
> for "d", I would like to select rows with sub-level "w".
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   u      1
>     v      2
> b   u      5
>     v      6
> d   w     11
>     w     15
> ```

```py
df.sort_index().select_rows({'one':['a','b'], 'two':['u','v']}, ('d','w'))
         col
one two     
a   u      1
    v      2
b   u      5
    v      6
d   w     11
    w     15
```

> #### Question 7
>
> How do I get all rows where values in level "two" are greater than 5?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> b   7      4
>     9      5
> c   7     10
> d   6     11
>     8     12
>     8     13
>     6     15
> ```

With a dictionary, you can pass a function, as long as it can be evaluated on  an Index object:

```py
df2.select_rows({'two': lambda df: df > 5})
         col
one two     
b   7      4
    9      5
c   7     10
d   6     11
    8     12
    8     13
    6     15
```

You can select on columns with the [select_columns](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select_columns) function. There is also a generic [select](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select) function for selecting on both rows and columns.

The functions are extensible: let's see how it works with @double0darbo answer:

```py
df.select_rows({'country':['Oman', 'Nairobi']})
                                 Count A  Count B
gender thrown   country name                     
female scissors Oman    Pat         70.0     70.0
       paper    Oman    Casey       70.0     70.0
       rock     Oman    Thomy       70.0     70.0
male   rock     Nairobi Chris       12.0     12.0
       scissors Nairobi Musa        12.0     12.0
       paper    Nairobi Michele     12.0     12.0
```

Attempting @r a answer as well:

```py
df.select_rows({1:'stock1', 2:'velocity'})
                    0
a stock1 velocity   3
b stock1 velocity  12

df.select_rows({1:['stock1','stock3'], 2:'velocity'})
                    0
a stock1 velocity   3
b stock1 velocity  12
a stock3 velocity   9
b stock3 velocity  18

df.select_rows({0:slice('a',None), 1:['stock1','stock3'], 2:'velocity'})
                    0
a stock1 velocity   3
  stock3 velocity   9
b stock1 velocity  12
  stock3 velocity  18
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with pandas multi-indices is quite difficult typically, therefore, i created a small helper library [pandas-indexing](https://github.com/coroa/pandas-indexing/) to simplify working with them, it contains a set of selectors to query elegantly into a multiindex:

```py
from pandas_indexing import isin
```

> #### Question 1
>
> How do I select rows having "a" in level "one"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   t      0
>     u      1
>     v      2
>     w      3
> ```

```py
df.loc[isin(one="a")]
```

> Additionally, how would I be able to drop level "one" in the output?
>
> ```
>      col
> two     
> t      0
> u      1
> v      2
> w      3
> ```

Well, drop it, then.

```py
df.loc[isin(one="a")].droplevel("one")
```

---

> #### Question 1b
>
> How do I slice all rows with value "t" on level "two"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   t      0
> b   t      4
>     t      8
> d   t     12
> ```

```py
df.loc[isin(two="t")]
```

This is much, much cleaner.

---

> #### Question 2
>
> How can I select rows corresponding to items "b" and "d" in level "one"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> b   t      4
>     u      5
>     v      6
>     w      7
>     t      8
> d   w     11
>     t     12
>     u     13
>     v     14
>     w     15
> ```

Using loc, this is done in a similar fashion by specifying a list.

```
df.loc[isin(one=["b", "d"])]
```

---

> #### Question 2b
>
> How would I get all values corresponding to "t" and "w" in level "two"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   t      0
>     w      3
> b   t      4
>     w      7
>     t      8
> d   w     11
>     t     12
>     w     15
> ```

```
df.loc[isin(two=["t", "w"])]
```

---

> #### Question 3
>
> How do I retrieve a cross section, i.e., a single row having a specific values
> for the index from `df`? Specifically, how do I retrieve the cross
> section of `('c', 'u')`, given by
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> c   u      9
> ```

```
df.loc[isin(one="c", two="u")]
```

---

> #### Question 4
>
> How do I select the two rows corresponding to `('c', 'u')`, and `('a', 'w')`?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> c   u      9
> a   w      3
> ```

Since `isin` assumes an *and* between different levels and an *or* between different values, the intuitive solution:

```
df.loc[isin(one=["c", "a"], two=["u", "w"])]
```

would also select `("c", "w")` which you probably don't want, but you can combine the selectors easily:

```
df.loc[isin(one="c", two="u") | isin(one="a", two="w")]
```

or if you have a list of them use `semijoin`

```
from pandas_indexing import semijoin
semijoin(df, pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("c", "u"), ("a", "w")], names=["one", "two"]))
```

---

> #### Question 5
>
> How can I retrieve all rows corresponding to "a" in level "one" or
> "t" in level "two"?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   t      0
>     u      1
>     v      2
>     w      3
> b   t      4
>     t      8
> d   t     12
> ```

```
df.loc[isin(one="a") | isin(two="t")]
```

---

> #### Question 6
>
> How can I slice specific cross sections? For "a" and "b", I would like to select all rows with sub-levels "u" and "v", and
> for "d", I would like to select rows with sub-level "w".
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   u      1
>     v      2
> b   u      5
>     v      6
> d   w     11
>     w     15
> ```

```
df.loc[isin(one=["a", "b"], two=["u", "v"]) | isin(one="d", two="w")]
```

---

> #### Question 7
>
> How do I get all rows where values in level "two" are greater than 5?
>
> ```
>          col
> one two     
> b   7      4
>     9      5
> c   7     10
> d   6     11
>     8     12
>     8     13
>     6     15
> ```

From version 0.2.6:

```
df2.loc[isin(two=lambda s: s > 5)]
```