# Sort DataFrame on column of intervals

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, categories

My output looks like this:

```
     binnedb   Proba-A   Proba-B Esperance-A Esperance-B
0    (0.0101, 0.0202]  0.547826  0.539130    0.007817    0.007693
1    (0.0302, 0.0402]  0.547826  0.539130    0.005963    0.005854
2    (0.0201, 0.0302]  0.547826  0.539130    0.008360    0.008227
```

What I would like to do is to sort the df in an ascending order based on the binnedb column(which will be also sorted in ascending order). Please let me know if you don't understand the question. That is what I tried so far: `df.sort_values(by=['binnedb'], ascending = False)`

But it does not work... thanks!

Comment: What is `type(df['binnedb'])`?

Comment: A bin : `bins = np.linspace(0, 1, num=100)`

Comment: No no, my question was, what does `type(df['binnedb'])` print? I want to know if it is a categorical column. For example, it should say `pandas.core.arrays.categorical.Categorical`

Comment: that is what it prints: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: it goes from (0.00 to 1]

Comment: Does printing `df['binnedb'].cat.codes` work or throw an error?

Comment: it works in my case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is `inverval` type column , you can using `left` to get the left range and sort base on it .

```
df['sortkey']=df.binnedb.map(lambda x : x.left)
df=df.sort_values('sortkey')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the first line of code does not seem to take the left value of the interval... any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

Interval columns are actually categorical columns which follow a specific ordering. If "binnedb" is categorical column, you can access its category codes and use `argsort`:

```
df = df.iloc[df['binnedb'].cat.codes.argsort()]
```

Comment: @W-B and to you as well :)

Comment: @AmiTavory No problem. The original link was for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/how-do-i-slice-or-filter-mutliindex-dataframe-levels/53927461#53927461 But actually, I have a list of all the pandas canonicals I have written (all of them written last month) in my About Me, under the heading "(Actively Maintained) Pandas Canonicals". Please do go through them when you have the time. Thanks again :)