# Add new key in dicts in a list whose value is the index

Tags: python, pandas

```
df.at[0, 'A'] = [{'score': 12, 'player': [{'name': 'Jacob', 'score': 2},
                                          {'name': 'Shane', 'score': 5}, ...]},
                 {'score': 33, 'player': [{'name': 'Cindy', 'score': 4}, ...]}, ...]
```

Say I have a list of n dictionaries for column 'A' in a data frame like above. I want to add a new key named 'game' which is the index of the list. So, it'd be like below.

```
df.at[0, 'A'] = [{'score': 12, 'player': [...], 'game': 0},
                 {'score': 33, 'player': [...], 'game': 1}, ...]
```

Since I have to do the same thing with 'player', I don't want to use `for` loops.
Is there a way to achieve this?

---

```
df.at[0, 'A'][0]['player'] = [{'name': 'Jacob', 'score': 2, 'number': 0},
                              {'name': 'Shane', 'score': 5, 'number': 1}, ...]}
```

For example, 'player' will have key 'number' whose value is the index of the inner list.

---

Basically, I don't want to use any nested `for` loop to do this because the actual data I have received is a way larger NL data that actually came in that ridiculous form.

Comment: I don't understand your reason for not using a `for` loop. What do you mean about doing the same thing with `player`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your data structure, Barmar is probably right that you're stuck with a `for` loop (which there's nothing wrong with, by-the-by). Here's a couple of potential work-arounds.

## A "solution"

The information you're trying to record is redundant, so you probably don't need to bother with it in the first place.

Basically what you're saying is that the value of `game` and `number` are already encoded by the position of each element in its list. Chances are that there's a way to get whatever final result you're trying to compute while also skipping writing out all of this redundant information.

## A larger point

You're trying to wrangle a large set of data with a complicated structure. You're probably about at the limit of what you can reasonably deal with using the kind of ad-hoc structure you posted. Here are some better ways:

- If you can figure out a way to flatten your data (or least to make it "rectangular", in a sense), then you may be able to wrangle it into a [Numpy array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). Numpy hits a nice sweet spot between extremely fast and easy to use.
- You could convert the inner dictionaries into more levels in your dataframe, to make a sort of hierarchical dataframe with an associated [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#multiindex-advanced-indexing). There's a good SO thread with a lot more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53927460/425458).
- While not necessarily the most performant option, one really good way to make it easier to understand data with a complex structure is to represent that structure as a hierarchy of [user-defined objects](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/thinkpython016.html). In the past I've found this to be a very fruitful way to uncover hidden relationships in data (though like I said, it can be slow).

Comment: So true. I gave up keeping the original structure and have been re-structuring the data. I needed the index so I can match it with the original text after dropping irrelevant sentences. (That is, the 'score'.) The index is the position of a sentence. The index of the inner list (the 'player') is the position of a word in that sentence. BTW, thanks for the links, I guess I can try them later.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your reason for not wanting to use a `for` loop. If you can get over that, it would be:

```
for i, d in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
    d['game'] = i
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll try to explain better next time so others don't get confused.