# Selecting range on multi index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a multiindex (module_id, id).
I'm trying to select all row less than or equal to 2.2 (module_id.id)

```
                calculated
module_id id
1       1           False
        2           False
        3           False
2       1           True
        2           True
        3           True
```

How would you do this?

Comment: Where's 2.2 in your DataFrame?

Comment: Perhaps [Select rows in pandas MultiIndex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/how-do-i-slice-or-filter-multiindex-dataframe-levels/53927461#53927461) might be useful.

Comment: So long as your index is lexsorted (can check with `df.index.is_lexsorted()`) the normal slicing works: `df[:(2,2)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(based on @ALollz comment, which is the right answer)

`df[:(2,2)]`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to select records bigger or equal than 2, 2 (2 in first and second column) so you have to do:

```
df.query('module_id >= 2 & id >= 2')
```

Comment: Please consider adding some context around your code so we know what it does and why.