# Reading excel files in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read an Excel file using pandas but I am not sure if I am able to read the way I need.

My file is like this:

[image]

I am reading the file like this:

```
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile('MY_FILE')
df = excel_file.parse(sheet_name=0, header=1)
```

This way I am able to read but I am not sure from which group each variable belongs. In this case, for each column I need to know from which group they are coming from. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible specify first and second row in parameter `header` for `MultiIndex` in columns and `index_col` for index from first column in function [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=[0,1], index_col=[0], sheet_name=0)
```

Your solution should be changed with same parameters:

```
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')
df = excel_file.parse(header=[0,1], index_col=[0], sheet_name=0)
```

---

```
print (df)
CUSTOM NAME   g1      g2          
NAME           A    B  A    B    C
NAME 1       1.0  NaN  1  NaN  1.0
NAME 1       NaN  1.0  1  1.0  NaN

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['g1', 'g2'], ['A', 'B', 'C']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 2]],
           names=['CUSTOM NAME', 'NAME'])

print (df.index)
Index(['NAME 1', 'NAME 1'], dtype='object')
```

Filtering working with tuples for select columns of `MultiIndex`:

```
print (df[df[('g1', 'A')] == 1])
CUSTOM NAME   g1     g2         
NAME           A   B  A   B    C
NAME 1       1.0 NaN  1 NaN  1.0
```

More information in [`Select rows in pandas MultiIndex DataFrame`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53927460/2901002), only remove `loc`, because `MultiIndex` in columns.

Comment: in this case do you know how could I filter for example for G1.A when value is equals to 1.0? Super thanks!

Comment: `df['GROUP 1']['A'] == 1.0`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MultiIndex` if you pass a list of integers to `header`:

```
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile('example.xlsx')
df = excel_file.parse(sheet_name=0, header=[0,1])
```

the dataframe:

```
CUSTOM NAME     GROUP 1     GROUP 2
NAME            A   B       A   B   C
NAME 1          1.0 NaN     1   NaN 1.0
NAME 2          NaN 1.0     1   1.0 NaN
```

Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: What is your pandas version? Because in pandas 0.24.2 is necessary solution like in my answer, your solution create MultiIndex also from first column, instead index.

Answer (score 1):

Reading column names **only** from row *1* will probably lead to repeating column
names, so such a call can end up with execution error.

It looks like you have a case of **MultiIndex** on columns:

- *GROUP 1* and  *GROUP 2* is the top level,
- *A*, *B* and *C* is the subordinate level.

When reading *Excel* files, I usually use *pd.read_excel* method.

In your case, you probably should pass *header=[0,1]* parameter,
specifying which rows contain column names.

So try something like:

```
df = pd.read_excel('MY_FILE.xls', header=[0,1])
```

You can also omit *sheet_name=0*, as this is the default value (read
from the first sheet, sheet numbering is from 0).

I'm also not sure whether you can omit file extension (either *xls* or
*xlsx*), so in the above proposal I wrote it explicitely.