# Converting lists of lists of tuples to MultiIndex pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a structure like this:

```
[
  [
    ('2019-12-01', '0.03555', '0.03', '0.03', '0.03'), 
    ('2019-12-02', '0.03', '0.03', '1', '0.03')
  ],
  [
    ('2019-12-01', '0.111', '0.02', '0.03', '0.03'), 
    ('2019-12-02', '0.03', '0.03', '0.03', '0.03')
  ]
]
```

I would like each list entry to be an index in a pandas dataframe, with the tuples being rows in the df. Something like this:

```
                         LIST_1                      LIST_2
         date      p1    p2     p3    p4    |   p1    p2     p3    p4
0   2019-12-01  0.03555  0.03  0.03   0.03  | 0.03  0.03  0.03   0.03
1   2019-12-02     0.03  0.03     1   0.03  | 0.03  0.03  0.03   0.03
```

I know this is messy, to be honest, I'm unsure the best way to structure it in Pandas as I'm new to it, so any advice would be appreciated.

I have tried to flatten the strucutre using:

`d = pd.DataFrame([t for lst in a for t in lst])`

But then I just end up with a df as expect like this:

```
        0          1     2     3      4
0   2019-12-01  0.03555  0.03  0.03   0.03
1   2019-12-02     0.03  0.03     1   0.03
2   2019-12-01    0.111  0.02  0.03   0.03
3   2019-12-02     0.03  0.03  0.03   0.03
```

But this isn't suitable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension for create first level of `MultiIndex` by `range` with length of list `lst` with `f-string`s.

Then use main list comprehension by all values of list with convert inner list to `DateFrame`s, create index by first column by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then rename columns by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html).

Last join all list of DataFrames by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `keys` parameter for first level of `MultiIndex` and remove index name `0` by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
L = [f'LIST_{i}' for i in range(1, len(lst)+1)]
df = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x).set_index(0).add_prefix('p') for x in lst], axis=1, keys=L)
        .rename_axis(None))
print (df)
             LIST_1                   LIST_2                  
                 p1    p2    p3    p4     p1    p2    p3    p4
2019-12-01  0.03555  0.03  0.03  0.03  0.111  0.02  0.03  0.03
2019-12-02     0.03  0.03     1  0.03   0.03  0.03  0.03  0.03
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael  :D - are you able to just edit the post and describe what each section is doing? will help me consolidate my understanding rather than just ctrl-c and ctrl-v - also could you show me an example of how to query such a structure

Comment: @Bob - I think for selecting you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe/53927461#53927461)

Comment: Thanks for the edit and will take a look at that post.

Comment: Whats the best way for me to add an index to the first col on the MultiIndex df

Comment: @Bob - hmmm, I think it is possible by `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: Yes I just got it as you replied `.rename_axis(NAME)` works :D

Comment: do you have any idea how I would group_by and sum the multiIndex ?