# get pandas datframe values by key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, key

I have this dataframe,

```
import pandas as pd

one = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'Name': ['Alex', 'Amy', 'Allen', 'Alice', 'Ayoung'],
    'subject_id':['sub1','sub2','sub3','sub4','sub5'],
    'Marks_scored':[98,90,87,69,78],
    'Rank': [1,1,2,10,7]})

two = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'Name': ['Billy', 'Brian', 'Bran', 'Bryce', 'Betty'],
    'subject_id':['sub1','sub2','sub3','sub7','sub8'],
    'Marks_scored':[89,80,79,97,88],
    'Rank': [1,2,5,1,2]})
```

I have concatenated these two dataframes like this.

```
df = pd.concat([one,two],keys=['x','y'])
```

Now I want only the values from key `'x'` only. How can I achieve that?

Comment: this might be a good read [Select rows in pandas MultiIndex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe)

Comment: Thanks @anky It's really good source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
print (df.loc['x'])
print (df.xs('x'))
```

---

```
   id    Name subject_id  Marks_scored  Rank
0   1    Alex       sub1            98     1
1   2     Amy       sub2            90     1
2   3   Allen       sub3            87     2
3   4   Alice       sub4            69    10
4   5  Ayoung       sub5            78     7
```