# Pandas Multi Index on columns: how to select all columns by part of string on column name

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Here is my Pandas DataFrame, I heavily use Multi Index on columns.

[image: DataFrame with complex MultiIndex on columns]

How to select, display and iterate over all columns that contain string “escala de 0-10” on level `field_title`?

Comment: This question might be useful for you to read up on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a boolean indexing mask using `Index.get_level_values` and `str.contains`:

```
lvl = 'field_name'
s = "escala de 0-10"

df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(lvl).str.contains(s)]
```