# MultiIndex: advanced indexing - how to select different parts of DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, indexing, multi-index

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
```

The matrix I have is df2. Now I want to select all the rows of 'foo', 'one' & 'two', but only the 'one' row of multiIndex 'bar'. This seems very easy but I have tried multiple things without succes.

```
df2.loc['bar':('foo','one')]
```

, Produces a similar matrix but including the rows of 'baz' that I don't want.

```
df2.loc[idx['foo','bar'],idx['one','two'], :]
```

, also similar but the second row of 'foo', 'two' I don't want.

Would be great if anybody could help and has some tips for handling the multiIndex!

Comment: I'm really confident [Select rows in MultiIndex dataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe/53927461#53927461) will help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! will have a look

Comment: In the meantime this seems like the fastest way to solve your problem: `pd.concat([df.loc[['foo']], df.loc[[('bar', 'one')]]])  `

Answer (score 1):

In a single line, the simplest way IMO is to build an expression with query, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe/53927461#53927461):

```
df.query("ilevel_0 == 'foo' or (ilevel_0 == 'bar' and ilevel_1 == 'one')") 

                0         1         2         3
bar one  0.249768  0.619312  1.851270 -0.593451
foo one  0.770139 -2.205407  0.359475 -0.754134
    two -1.109005 -0.802934  0.874133  0.135057
```

---

Otherwise, using more conventional means, you may consider

```
pd.concat([df.loc[['foo']], df.loc[[('bar', 'one')]]]) 

                0         1         2         3
foo one  0.770139 -2.205407  0.359475 -0.754134
    two -1.109005 -0.802934  0.874133  0.135057
bar one  0.249768  0.619312  1.851270 -0.593451
```

Which has two parts:

```
df.loc[['foo']]

                0         1         2         3
foo one  0.770139 -2.205407  0.359475 -0.754134
    two -1.109005 -0.802934  0.874133  0.135057
```

and,

```
df.loc[[('bar', 'one')]]

                0         1        2         3
bar one  0.249768  0.619312  1.85127 -0.593451
```

The braces around each index are to prevent the level from being dropped during the slicing operation.