# Slicing MultiIndexed DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have the following `DataFrame` named pop:

```py
California  2000    33871648
            2010    37253956
New York    2000    18976457
            2010    19378102
Texas       2000    20851820
            2010    25145561
```

I want to print out values of 2010 in California and Texas. Whenever I try `pop[['California','Texas'], 2010]` I meet the error `'(['California', 'Texas'], 2010)' is an invalid key`
How can I print the information then?

Comment: Should have mentioned, it is dataframe with several levels of indexes: State name and year respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR

```
df.loc[(level_1_indices_list, level_2_indices_list), :]
```

which is, in this case:

```
df.loc[(['California','Texas'], ['2010']), :]
```

*Below is a more elaborated version.*

---

```
# import packages & set seed
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(42)
```

---

## Create example dataframe

Using [the Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html):

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=arrays)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
```

This will look like:

[image]

---

## Slicing using multiindex

With `df` you can do:

```
df.loc[(['qux','foo'], 'one'), :]
```

For notational consistency you can use `[]` on the second element of the slice:

```
df.loc[(['qux','foo'], ['one']), :]
```

which will yield the same result.

Which is:

[image]

*(Selecting `'one'` is equivalent to selecting `2010` in your `df`. `['qux','foo']` should be equivalent to selecting ['California','Texas']. Based on this, I think you can apply the steps here to your data.)*

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53927461/8565438) might also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would something like this with specifying column names which can be extended further by adding more `&`

`df.loc[(df['level_0'].isin(['California', 'Texas'])) & (df['level_1'].isin(['2010']))]`

Comment: how to interpret ```'level_0'``` and ```'level_1'```?

Comment: Those are your column names