# How to slice a dataframe with multi index by row number (which is not in index) without destroying the index?

Tags: python, pandas, warnings, deprecated, deprecation-warning

Pandas 1.1.4

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    list('aaaabbbbbccddddd'),
    list('tuvwtuvwtuvwtuvw')
], names=['one', 'two'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.arange(len(mux))}, mux)
df["col2"] = 5    

print(df)
```

> ```
>          col  col2
> one two           
> a   t      0     5
>     u      1     5
>     v      2     5
>     w      3     5
> b   t      4     5
>     u      5     5
>     v      6     5
>     w      7     5
>     t      8     5
> c   u      9     5
>     v     10     5
> d   w     11     5
>     t     12     5
>     u     13     5
>     v     14     5
>     w     15     5
> ```

Now

```
df.loc[2:10, "col"] = 999
```

gives the expected result

> ```
> one two           
> a   t      0     5
>     u      1     5
>     v    999     5
>     w    999     5
> b   t    999     5
>     u    999     5
>     v    999     5
>     w    999     5
>     t    999     5
> c   u    999     5
>     v     10     5
> d   w     11     5
>     t     12     5
>     u     13     5
>     v     14     5
>     w     15     5
> ```

but warns

> FutureWarning: Slicing a positional slice with .loc is not supported,
> and will raise TypeError in a future version.  Use .loc with labels or
> .iloc with positions instead.   df.loc[2:10, "col"] = 999

---

Doing

`df["col"].iloc[2:10] = 999`

gives another (worse) warning:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

---

How to do this correctly, while keeping the index?

I couldn't find this use case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe)

Comment: The warning indicates a possible solution, using `iloc`: ``df.iloc[2:10, 0] = 999``

Comment: @sammywemmy please see edit for why I can't do that.

Comment: `df.iloc[2:10, 0] = 999` does everything in one go. Why the need to select `col` before `iloc`? any particular reason? You could also try `df.loc[:, "col"].iloc[2:10]`; I just feel less is more.

Comment: @sammywemmy `df.iloc[2:10, 0] = 999` relies on "col" being first, and the programmer knowing that. `df.loc[:, "col"].iloc[2:10]` gives `SettingWithCopyWarning` as stated in the edit.

Comment: can do the extremely ugly `df.iloc[2:10, np.where("col"==df.columns)[0]] = 999` but I was expecting a much cleaner standard appoach

Comment: How about getting the index location with `get_loc` : ``df.iloc[2:10, df.columns.get_loc("col")] = 999`` or ``df.loc(axis=1)["col"].iloc[2:10] = 999``. Not sure why you are getting the SettingWIthCopyWarning though

Comment: @sammywemmy I ended up doing that. it makes little sense that I would have to do that. There must be a solution we don't know

Comment: Multiindex selection is primarily by labels; you are selecting by position.