# Select multiple keys in multiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

d_foo = {}
d_foo[('a',1,'w')] = 1
d_foo[('b',2,'x')] = 1
d_foo[('c',2,'y')] = 1
d_foo[('d',3,'z')] = 1

df = pd.Series(d_foo)

df_sel = df[:,2,:]
```

This results in the following Series:

```
        0
b   x   1
c   y   1
```

Now say instead of 2, I want to get all rows that have either 2 or 3 in the second position like so:

```
        0
b   x   1
c   y   1
d   z   1
```

Initially I tried:

```
df_sel = df[:,[2,3],:]
```

However this yielded the following error:

```
TypeError: '[2, 3]' is an invalid key
```

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe) I tried the answer to 2b:

```
df_sel = df[pd.IndexSlice[:,[2,3]],:]
```

However this yielded the same error as above.

Is it possible to select all rows with key 2 and 3 in the index in an elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `pd.IndexSlice`, you just passed the incorrect slice. With 3 levels you need to use `:` for the 0th and last level you don't need to slice on. Use `.loc` to select with this slice.

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.IndexSlice[:, [2,3], :]
df.loc[idx]

b  2  x    1
c  2  y    1
d  3  z    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! One small addition: As I need the 1st level to be dropped, I added df = df.droplevel(1)

Answer (score 3):

Basically to find a way to do proper logical indexing. See [pandas.index.get_level_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
import pandas as pd

d_foo = {}
d_foo[('a',1,'w')] = 1
d_foo[('b',2,'x')] = 1
d_foo[('c',2,'y')] = 1
d_foo[('d',3,'z')] = 1

df = pd.Series(d_foo)
df[df.index.get_level_values(1).isin([2,3])]
```

gives

```
b  2  x    1
c  2  y    1
d  3  z    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost the answer I was looking for. I realized that I oversimplified my example, my apologies. That is, next to selecting values from level 1, I also need to select some values from other levels at the same time. Unfortunately I did not manage to extend your suggestion  to my revised example.