# Iterate by level in Pandas multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Essentially, I have a multi-index that is first date-time, then integer value of the week number.

I want to select a week number, check some conditions of the data for that week, and if those conditions are satisfied, get the date-time level of the index.

Here's a simplified version:

```
# Dataframe creation
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2019', '1/4/2019')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B':[3, 4, 5, 6], 'C':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']}, index=index)

print(df)

            A  B  C
2019-01-01  1  3  a
2019-01-02  2  4  a
2019-01-03  3  5  b
2019-01-04  4  6  b
```

Then,

```
# make a multi-index with last column
df = df.set_index([df.index, 'C'])
print(df)

              A  B
           C      
2019-01-01 a  1  3
2019-01-02 a  2  4
2019-01-03 b  3  5
2019-01-04 b  4  6
```

Again, fine. [According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe), I would expect that `df.loc[['a']]` would yield

```
              A  B
           C      
2019-01-01 a  1  3
2019-01-02 a  2  4
```

However, I get a key/index error. I instead tried `df[df['C'] == 'a']`, but also with a resulting key/index error.

So the psuedo-code for what I want to achieve is something like:

```
df = df.set_index([df.index, 'C'])

for value in 'C' level:
    check some condition on 'B' variable.
    if condition:
       get date level for this value
```

This seems like it would be fairly simple if I could figure out how to slice by specified index level... What am I missing?

**Note:**

I realize that I could just leave the `C` variable as a column and then do something like:

```
for c in df.C.unique():
    if (df[df.C == c].B >= 4).any():
        dates = df[df.C == c].index
        print(dates)
```

However, now I'm fixated on understanding multi-indexes just to learn Pandas better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix: `query` works with level names:

```
df.query('C=="a"')
```

Output:

```
              A  B
           C      
2019-01-01 a  1  3
2019-01-02 a  2  4
```

---

A bit more details on multilevel indexing from [the official doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/advanced.html#basic-indexing-on-axis-with-multiindex). If you have multilevel index, you slice it by tuples `(first_level, second_level)`:

```
df.loc[('2019/01/01', 'a')]
```

So you can get all the rows with a second-level value:

```
df.loc[(slice(None), 'a'), :]
```

and you get:

```
              A  B
           C      
2019-01-01 a  1  3
2019-01-02 a  2  4
```

or you can use `xs`:

```
df.xs('a', level='C')
```

which give (note that the second level index is gone):

```
            A  B
2019-01-01  1  3
2019-01-02  2  4
```

---

**Finally**, what you are trying to do `for c in df.C.unique():` is more of `groupby`:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('C')['B'].transform('max')>=4].index
```

Output:

```
MultiIndex([('2019-01-01', 'a'),
            ('2019-01-02', 'a'),
            ('2019-01-03', 'b'),
            ('2019-01-04', 'b')],
           names=[None, 'C'])
```

Comment: That's a great answer. Thank you. I considered `groupby` but I actually need the start and end dates for each week where there is matching criteria, hence the iteration idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
df.loc[(slice(None), 'a'), :]
```

which will give you:

```
              A  B
           C      
2019-01-01 a  1  3
2019-01-02 a  2  4
```

This is based on Question 1b [of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53927461/8565438) to the question [Select rows in pandas MultiIndex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe).