# List of pd.IndexSlice

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Input :

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A0','A1'], ['B0','B1','B2','B3']])
columns = ['foo', 'bar']
t = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape((len(midx), len(columns))),
                    index=midx, columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
In [6]: t
Out[6]:
       foo  bar
A0 B0    0    1
   B1    2    3
   B2    4    5
   B3    6    7
A1 B0    8    9
   B1   10   11
   B2   12   13
   B3   14   15
```

Question:

Let `v = pd.IndexSlice['A0','B0':'B1']`. I can access `t.loc[v,:]`:

```
In [13]: t.loc[v,:]
Out[13]:
       foo  bar
A0 B0    0    1
   B1    2    3
```

From `[v,v]`, how can I get the following dataframe?

```
In [13]: f([v,v])
Out[13]:
       foo  bar
A0 B0    0    1
   B1    2    3
   B0    0    1
   B1    2    3
```

I can't specify a list of those multi-index slicers: `t.loc[[v,v],:]` will raise an Exception: `Unashable type: 'slice'`. Why is it so? When using scalars, I can easily list the desired locs: `t.loc[[('A0','B0'),('A0','B1')],:]`.

Comment: Please describe the expected output and we can tell you the best way for that slicing operation. Might also be worth looking into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe

Comment: Nope. I think this beyound the current limits of indexing multiIindex dataframes.   Here is a workaround `pd.concat([t.loc[v,:]]*2)`

Comment: Yep, I ended up using concat. I was just wondering... I thought `t.loc[[v,v],:]` would have been a good syntax to achieve that. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
t.loc[tuple(zip(v, v)),:]
```

It should be :

```
u = (['A0', 'A1'], [slice('B0', 'B1', None), slice('B0', 'B1', None)])
```

try to have it in the above form.

```
t.loc[u,:]
```

---

```
        foo bar
A0  B0  0   1
    B1  2   3
A1  B0  8   9
    B1  10  11
```

Comment: I edited my question for clarity on the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Use a little known nor used parameter `axis=0` of `loc`:

> You can also specify the axis argument to .loc to interpret the passed
> slicers on a single axis.

[Advanced indexing with hierarchical index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index)

```
t.loc(axis=0)[v]
```

Output:

```
       foo  bar
A0 B0    0    1
   B1    2    3
```

Work around per updated comments and question clarification:

```
pd.concat([t.loc[v,:]]*2)
```

Output:

```
       foo  bar
A0 B0    0    1
   B1    2    3
   B0    0    1
   B1    2    3
```

Comment: I edited my question for clarity on the desired output.