# Select rows with minimum mean column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a 3-level MultiIndex, for example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col0': [0,8,3,1,2,2,0,0],
    'col1': range(8),
}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0,1]] * 3, names=['idx0', 'idx1', 'idx2']))
>>> df
                col0  col1
idx0 idx1 idx2            
0    0    0        0     0
          1        8     1
     1    0        3     2
          1        1     3
1    0    0        2     4
          1        2     5
     1    0        0     6
          1        0     7
```

For each `idx0`, I want to find the `idx1` that has the lowest mean of `col0`. This gives me `idx0, idx1` pairs. Then I'd like to select all the rows matching those pairs.

In the example above, the pairs are `[(0, 1), (1, 1)]` (with means `2` and `0`, respectively) and the desired result is:

```
                col0  col1
idx0 idx1 idx2            
0    1    0        3     2
          1        1     3
1    1    0        0     6
          1        0     7
```

**What I have tried**

*Step 1:* Group by `idx0, idx1` and calculate the mean of `col0`:

```py
mean_col0 = df.groupby(['idx0', 'idx1'])['col0'].mean()
>>> mean_col0
idx0  idx1
0     0       4.0
      1       2.0
1     0       2.0
      1       0.0
```

*Step 2:* Select the indexmin (`idx1`) by group of `idx0`:

```py
level_idxs = mean_col0.groupby('idx0').idxmin()
>>> level_idxs
idx0
0    (0, 1)
1    (1, 1)
```

*Step 3:* Use that to filter the original dataframe.

That's the main problem. When I simply try `df.loc[ix]`, I get a `ValueError` due to shape mismatch. I would need the third index value or a wildcard.

I think I have a solution. Putting it all together with the steps above:

```
mean_col0 = df.groupby(['idx0', 'idx1'])['col0'].mean() 
level_idxs = mean_col0.groupby(["idx0"]).idxmin()
result = df[df.index.droplevel(2).isin(level_idxs)]
```

But it seems quite complicated. Is there a better way?

Comment: Give me a moment

Comment: Doesn't really matter. I need to find the minimum of the average blocks in one column. I added some sample code

Comment: I found a solution. It's not great, so I'm leaving this open in case someone has something less verbose to solve this.

Comment: I think your solution is pretty good (only 3 lines - 1 per each operation you're doing). By the way, your way of selecting the `level_idxs` is also proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53927461/14627505) (end of Question 4 - **"What if I have multiple levels?"**)

Comment: You could also use a (rather lengthy one-liner) like this: `df.reset_index(level=2).loc[df.groupby(["idx0", "idx1"])["col0"].mean().groupby(["idx0"]).idxmin()].set_index('idx2', append=True)`. Will get you the same result as your own solution. But it would be a lot slower in fact.

Comment: There is a step by step example. Two people at least understood it. And there is a minimal real example and the end with a solution. Not sure what I could provide more than that.

Comment: sure, see my edits (and feel free to revert if you prefer your original question). I tried to clarify and added a minimal reproducible example upfront. Also, your solution is optimal AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks, looks better now. I think the solutions posted in the answers down below is better than mine (see also my comments under this). And I still think there might be an even better solution than this.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "better". In terms of performance (speed), yours is faster and, I believe, optimal. (The speed up is between 50% to 700%, depending on size).

Comment: In general, readability and performance is important. Can you elaborate why my solution is so much faster? 
Just to be clear, I'm talking about my solution in the question compared to: 
`df.groupby('idx0', group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.xs(g.groupby('idx1')['col0'].mean().idxmin(), level=1, drop_level=False))`

Comment: Applying a function (esp. a lambda) is typ. slower than vectorized operations. In terms of readability --totally agree that it is desirable as well as performance. But it is a bit subjective; personally I find both approaches equally readable (and in fact it is by reading your code sample that I understood what you were looking for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

For each group of `idx0`: [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) only those `idx1`-s which have the smallest mean in `col0`:

```py
df.groupby('idx0').apply(lambda g:
        g.query(f"idx1 == {g.groupby('idx1')['col0'].mean().idxmin()}")
    ).droplevel(0)
```

The same can be written in this (hopefully more readable) way:

```py
def f(df):
    chosen_idx1 = df.groupby('idx1')['col0'].mean().idxmin()
    return df.query('idx1 == @chosen_idx1')

df.groupby('idx0').apply(f).droplevel(0)
```

Comment: It is not quite working as it repeats idx0, so the output will have two columns with idx0

Comment: @Leon0402, yes sorry, forgot to add `droplevel(0)` at the end. Updated. Now it should work.

Comment: I like the general idea of using `apply` here very much. This shows my intent more clearly!
I will play a little around it. Maybe it is possible to change the lambda so the drop level is not needed.

Comment: @Leon0402, seems like `.droplevel(0)`is necessary. Either at the end (like I have), or right before .query(): `g.droplevel(0).query(...)`, or after .query(): `g.query(...).droplevel(0)`

Comment: I found another way: You can also do `groupby('idx0', group_keys=False)`, which is better than dropping I think. 

And instead of query one can also use xs like this: 
`df.groupby('idx0', group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.xs(g.groupby('idx1')['col0'].mean().idxmin(), level=1, drop_level=False)) `
I don't know though if xs or query would be preferable.