# Slicing a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, multi-index

I have a "`pandas.MultiIndex.from_product`" data-frame from which I want to slice some data.
For these slices I know the (multi-) index.

The known index does not necessarily exist in the data-frame, it might be lower for the start-index (**b1**) or higher for the end-index (**b2**), see code `slice1`.

Here is a **minimal example** of my problem.

```
import pandas as pd

ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(3), range(3)], names=["a", "b"])
df = pd.DataFrame(range(0,9999,1111), columns=["values"], index=ind)

idx = pd.IndexSlice

slice1 = df.loc[idx[0:1, 1:3],:]
slice2 = df.loc[idx[0:2, 1:0],:]
```

In the pictures you see the data-frame `df`, `slice1` and the expected `slice2`. As long as **b1<b2** my code works perfectly fine but when **b1>b2** as it is in `slice2` it returns an empty data-frame.

[image: Data-Frame]
[image: Slice1]
[image: Slice2]

Is there a way to make this working? BTW, I saw this post here: [Select rows in pandas MultiIndex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe) but I don't think it answers this question.

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to achieve?  What is the expected output dataframe

Comment: The expected output of `slice2` is everything inside the red frame inside the third picture, similar to `slice1`. Basically what `df.iloc[1:7]` would return.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. I tried it way too complicated, this is the answer:

```
slice2 = df.loc[(0,1):(2,0),:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter:

```
slice2 = df[(0,1):(2,0)]
```

Comment: True this works as well. What is the difference between `df[...]` and `df.loc[....]`

Comment: My understanding is that df.loc[..] also allows to access columns. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html
You can use df[] as a shortcut when you have a proper index (as you do in the Q)