# Pandas Multi-Index with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I applied the .loc methodolgy discussed in [Select rows in pandas MultiIndex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe) because I was recieving a KeyError:'class' even though 'class' exists as (what I thought was a column name) in my existing dataframe. Later finding out that 'class' was one of two indexes in a multiindex ('group' being the secondary index). While the .loc function allows me to select rows with 'First','Second','Third' I'm struggling to determine how to then apply an additional condition to exclude rows where the second index ('group') has blank rows.

Current dataframe looks like this:

| class | group | Column1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | A | 123 |
| First |  |  |
| Second | B | 123 |
| Third | C | 123 |
| Forth | D | 123 |

Current code looks like this:

```
keep_rows = df.loc[['First','Second','Third']]
```

My original code looked like this (and was throwing the KeyError due to referenced names beind indexs and not column names)

```
keep_rows = df[(df['class'].isin(['First','Second','Third'])) & (df['group'].isna())]
```

Desired dataframe:

| class | group | Column1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | A | 123 |
| Second | B | 123 |
| Third | C | 123 |

Comment: Try your solution with notna() with reset index

Comment: keep_rows = df.reset_index().loc[df['class'].isin(['First', 'Second', 'Third']) & df['group'].notna()]

Comment: df = df.dropna()[['class', 'group', 'Column1']].head(3) may be a little clunky, but it gives the desired dataframe :).

Comment: @Moid your script resulted in the original error KeyError: 'class'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
>>> df[(df.index.get_level_values('class').isin(['First','Second','Third'])) 
       & (df.index.get_level_values('group') != '')]

              Column1
class  group         
First  A        123.0
Second B        123.0
Third  C        123.0
```

Details:

```
>>> df.index.get_level_values('class').isin(['First','Second','Third'])
array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False])

>>> df.index.get_level_values('group').notna()
array([ True, False,  True,  True,  True])
```

Comment: This ran successfully but did not remove the rows with blank values in the 'group' column.

Comment: Probably because you have no `NaN` values but empty or `'NaN'` string?

Comment: within the df, the cells are empty. is there another way to remove these rows?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `print(df.index)`

Comment: MultiIndex([( 'First',  'A'),( 'First',  ''),( 'Second',  'B'),( 'Third',  'C')], names=['class','group'])

Comment: So you have to check the empty string (I updated my answer) and not the null value.

Comment: Yep, I applied the above change and it was successful. Accepted your answer. Thank you!